# Access dom-repeat element's CSS class on tap

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

My dom repeat displays a list of icons which I can bookmark or unbookmark ,which generating dom-repeat I call a function to find if this icon is bookmarked or not,that will return CSS class

```
 .book-marked {
    color: red;
  }

  .not-book-marked {
    color: green;
  }

  <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{membersList}}">    
        <iron-icon icon="bookmark" class$="[[_computeBookMark(item.userId)]]" on-tap="_toogleBookMark"></iron-icon>     
  </template>
```

Once I get all my list of icon now if user click that icon I need to toogle css class.so I wrote on-tap function

```
  _toogleBookMark:function(e) {
    var userData = e.model.item;  //gets entire data object of that element
    var index = e.model.index;    //gets index of that element
  },
```

I can't use ID since its dom-repeat ,Is there any other ways so that I can change CSS of that dom-repeat element in _toogleBookMark() function on clicking? or is it possible to change CSS with index??or using "e" reference in _toogleBookMark(e) function !!

Comment: You can keep your `class` or `id` name something like `myClass0` where 0 is the index and then in click handler you can refer that class using the index(myClass+e.model.index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly - you want to access the element you've tapped?

Just use the event.target property then. It will return the element on which the event happened, in this case, the icon you have tapped.

```
_toogleBookMark = function(e) {
e.target.classList.toggle("not-book-marked");
```

}

Check this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/2q3fqehz/113/).

Mind you:

1) When using Shady DOM, assuming our element is a custom element, target can be a component from the element's template, not the element itself. To prevent that, use Polymer.dom(e).localTarget (read more [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events)).

2) When using a custom element with light DOM children, the above may not be enough, your (local)target will be a light DOM child, not the element you wished for. In that case, use Element.closest(selector) to (optionally) go up the DOM to the element you want. Read more about the method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Answer (score 0):

As you just want to swap your class on tap, do it like this:

Add an  own attribute, like `data-id="1"` and the `id` attribute, but be sure they have the same value:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{membersList}}">    
    <iron-icon icon="bookmark" class$="[[_computeBookMark(item.userId)]]" on-tap="_toogleBookMark" data-id="{{item.userId}}" id="{{item.userId}}"></iron-icon>     
</template>
```

Now, inside your `_toggleBookMark` function, you can access the current tapped element and swap CSS classes by:

```
_toogleBookMark:function(e) {
    // this gives you your userId from the data-id attribute
    var userId = e.path[0].dataId; 

    // we can access the element now with
    var element = this.$$('#' + e.path[0].dataId);

    if (element.classList.contains('book-marked')) {
      element.classList.remove('book-marked');
      element.classList.add('not-book-marked');
    } else {
      element.classList.add('book-marked');
      element.classList.remove('not-book-marked');
    }
},
```

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your question a bit. I'll update my answer.